# Problemas para capturar tecla Enter no Android

Tags: android, mobile, firemonkey, delphi-10

Estou tendo problemas para capturar a tecla **`Enter`** no `Android`

```
begin 
if(Key = 13)then 

ShowMessage('Você teclou '+ KeyChar);//Para testar se estava capturando algo

end;
```

Só recebo retorno pressiono a tecla de apagar texto.
Também tentei

```
Uses AndroidApi.KeyCode
if(Key = AKEYCODE_ENTER)
```

Mas não funcionou.
Já testei tanto no `KeyDown` quanto no `KeyUp`

Comment: No evento `KeyDown` tenta `if (Key = VK_RETURN)`

Comment: Sendo bem honesto, não sei qual das duas medidas funcionou, mas eu fiz isso e alterei no edit a propriedade ReturnKey de Default p/outra e foi.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O que resolve e exatamente isso, alterar a propriedade returnekey. Apos isso ele recebe os valores do teclado fisico.